# Ruby mixin - multiple inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance, mixins

I have recently learned how to implement inheritance through modules. However, I cannot see clean solution if I wanted to implement multiple inheritance.
Here's the original example that uses single inheritance and calls initialize methods of superclasses.:

```
module ModuleB  
  def initialize
    puts "initialize from ModuleB"
    @b = 5
  end
end

module ModuleA
  include ModuleB

  def initialize
    super
    puts "initialize from ModuleA"
    @a = @b
  end

  def action_1
    @a = @b + 1
  end
end

class ClassA
  include ModuleA
  def initialize
    super
    puts 'initialize - method in ClassA'
    @c = @a
    @d = @b
    puts "a = #@a"
    puts "b = #@b"
    puts "c = #@c"
    puts "d = #@d"
  end

end

instA = ClassA.new
puts instA.action_1
```

However, if there was additional ModuleC included in ClassA, how would we invoke "superclasses" initialize mehods?

```
    module ModuleB  
      def initialize
        puts "initialize from ModuleB"
        @b = 5
      end
    end

    module ModuleA
      include ModuleB

      def initialize
        super
        puts "initialize from ModuleA"
        @a = @b
      end

      def action_1
        @a = @b+1
        @a = @b + 1
      end
    end

    module ModuleC
      include ModuleB

      def initialize
        super
        puts "initialize from ModuleC"
        @a = 'cute Zuzia'
      end

      def action_1
        @a = 'something'
      end
    end


    class ClassA
      include ModuleA
      include ModuleC
      def initialize
        super  # which initialize will be called? From moduleA or from moduleC?
                # what if I wanted to invoke ModuleC initialize from classA instance as well?
        puts 'initialize - method in ClassA'
        @c = @a
        @d = @b
        puts "a = #@a"
        puts "b = #@b"
        puts "c = #@c"
        puts "d = #@d"
      end

    end
```

How to enable multiple inheritance with mixin in that case?

Comment: I get that this code is "just for fun", but I don't think you'd *ever* want to define an `initialize` method in a `module` - that's just asking for trouble. Similarly, I'd be terrified of any code that mixed methods between modules like that... So although you are correct that the language's behaviour is somewhat unclear (just like any complicated inheritance example, in any language!), this is a very unrealistic code example you're experimenting with.

Answer (score 4):

> which initialize will be called? From moduleA or from moduleC?

```
class C
  include M
end
```

is very simple: it makes `M` the superclass of `C` and the former superclass of `C` the superclass of `M`. In other words, it is nothing but bog-standard boring old class inheritance. (To be more precise: it creates a class which shares its method table pointer, constant table pointer, and class variable table pointer with `M` and makes that class the superclass of `C` and the former superclass of `C` the superclass of this newly-created class. It also checks if `M` is already in `C`'s ancestry chain, in which case it simply does nothing.)

```
module M1
  include M2
end
```

Obviously, this cannot make `M2` the superclass of `M1`, because modules don't have superclasses. What it does instead, is simply record the fact that `M2` is an ancestor of `M1`, so that in the future, when `M1` is `include`d into a class and a class is created for `M1`, `M2` will be included into this newly created class.

So, it's all just class inheritance. Simple, boring, class inheritance.

Let's just look at the situation in your code:

```
module ModuleB; end
```

Okay, so we have defined a module called `ModuleB`.

```
module ModuleA
  include ModuleB
end
```

And we have defined a module named `ModuleA`, which somewhere inside of it has stored the fact that when it gets `include`d into a class, `ModuleB` should be `include`d as well. (Let's just pretend that there's an instance variable `@__included_modules__` or something like that and that `Module#include` is just implemented as `@__included_modules__ << m`).

```
module ModuleC
  include ModuleB
end
```

Here again we have defined a module named `ModuleC`, which somewhere inside of it has stored the fact that when it gets `include`d into a class, `ModuleB` should be `include`d as well.

```
class ClassA
  include ModuleA
  include ModuleC
end
```

Let's step through this.

1. `ClassA`'s superclass is `Object` (which is the implicit superclass if none is specified explicitly).
2. `include ModuleA` first checks if `ModuleA` is already in `ClassA`'s ancestry chain. It isn't.
3. So, it creates a new class (let's call it `〚ModuleA′〛`).
4. It makes `Object` (`ClassA`'s current superclass) the superclass of `〚ModuleA′〛`
5. It makes `〚ModuleA′〛` the superclass of `ClassA`. At this point, the ancestry chain looks like this: `ClassA` → `〚ModuleA′〛` → `Object` → `Kernel` → `BasicObject`
6. Now it just repeats everything for every module that is recorded in `ModuleA` in the order it was recorded.
7. First, Ruby checks if `ModuleB` is already in `ClassA`'s ancestry chain. It isn't.
8. Ruby creates a class, let's call it `〚ModuleB′〛`
9. Ruby makes the current superclass of `〚ModuleA′〛`, which is of course `Object` the superclass of `〚ModuleB′〛`.
10. It makes `〚ModuleB′〛` the superclass of `〚ModuleA′〛`. At this point, the ancestry chain looks like this: `ClassA` → `〚ModuleA′〛` → `〚ModuleB′〛` → `Object` → `Kernel` → `BasicObject`.
11. Now we're done with the `include ModuleA` line and go on to `include ModuleC`. Again, it's all just the same simple steps:
12. `include ModuleC` first checks if `ModuleC` is already in `ClassA`'s ancestry chain. It isn't.
13. So, it creates a new class (let's call it `〚ModuleC′〛`).
14. It makes `〚ModuleA′〛` (`ClassA`'s current superclass) the superclass of `〚ModuleC′〛`
15. It makes `〚ModuleC′〛` the superclass of `ClassA`. At this point, the ancestry chain looks like this: `ClassA` → `〚ModuleC′〛` → `〚ModuleA′〛` → `〚ModuleB′〛` → `Object` → `Kernel` → `BasicObject`
16. Now it just repeats everything for every module that is recorded in `ModuleC` in the order it was recorded.
17. First, Ruby checks if `ModuleB` is already in `ClassA`'s ancestry chain. It is. So it won't get `include`d again.
18. We're done!

`ClassA`'s ancestry chain looks like this: `ClassA` → `〚ModuleC′〛` → `〚ModuleA′〛` → `〚ModuleB′〛` → `Object` → `Kernel` → `BasicObject`.

So, to repeat your question:

> which initialize will be called? From moduleA or from moduleC?

`super` simply takes "one step up" the ancestry chain. Since we are in `ClassA#initialize`, `super` will walk up the ancestry chain, starting with `ClassA`'s superclass until it finds another method with the same name. So, it will start in `〚ModuleC′〛`, where it indeed finds an `initialize` method and run that.

> what if I wanted to invoke `ModuleC#initialize` from `classA` instance as well?

Umm, that's what we just did, isn't it? Just call `super`.

Or do you mean *without* also calling `ClassA#initialize`? In that case what you can do is to get hold of the `ModuleC#initialize` directly and bind it to `instA`:

```
meth = ModuleC.instance_method(:initialize)
bound_meth = meth.bind(instA)
bound_meth.()
```

I know that a lot of Ruby tutorials make a big show of making all of this sound very complicated. But it isn't. `include` makes the module that is included the superclass of whatever it is included into. Period. It really is *that* simple. Mixin inheritance is just inheritance. Everything else, method lookup, constant lookup, `super`, whatever, it just works the same.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question "which initialize will be called? From moduleA or from moduleC?", it is the `intialize` of the `module` `include`-ed the last. This is a general rule in Ruby.

Your example did make me think a bit, even if you are doing this just for fun. I have a slightly different idea of how you could implement what you want to.

1) Create a module common to the `module`s that define `proc`s that do the job of your `initialize` methods. One drawback here is that I am mutating constants.

```
module C
    INIT = []
end

module A
    include C

    INIT << ->{puts "initialize() of Module A"}
end

module B
    include C

    INIT << ->{puts "initialize() of Module B"}
end

class D
    include A
    include B

    def initialize
        # Note that you don't need the 'C::' part here,
        # but it is safer.
        C::INIT.each(&:call)

        puts "initialize of class D"
    end
end

d = D.new
```

2.) Similar to above, but avoids constants. Uses `proc`s nevertheless.

```
module C
    @@initializers = []
    def add_initializer(proc)
        @@initializers << proc
    end

    def initializers
        @@initializers
    end
end

module A
    extend C

    add_initializer(->{puts "initialize() of Module A"})
end

module B
    extend C

    add_initializer(->{puts "initialize() of Module B"})
end

class D
    include A
    include B

    include C

    def initialize
        initializers.each(&:call)

        puts "initialize of class D"
    end
end

d = D.new
```

As an aside, the "registering code with `proc`s to execute at a later time" pattern is quite prominent in Rails.

**EDIT:**

If you want to do something more complicated than add a `puts` inside the body of the `proc`, you could instead invoke a method inside the body of the `proc` that does the heavy lifting you want.

I have changed the definition of `module A` as follows:

```
module A
    extend C

    class << self
        def initializer
            puts "initialize() of Module A"         
        end
    end

    add_initializer(->{initializer})
end
```

Comment: Your both solutions seem to be quite interesting. Though, how would `add_initializer` invocations look like if there was more complicated code than just a single `puts 'abc'`? Could a method name containing such code be passed to `add_initializer`? How would such code look like?

Comment: Good point. You could add a method invocation inside the body of the `proc`. This method would do the heavy lifting you need. I have added an **EDIT** section to my answer where I add this example.